# Give me an example of performing an xpath query on a KML document, from Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I am looking into the use of xpath from within Javascript.

I have an XMLHttpRequest(), which retrieves a KML document. KML is just a particular flavor of XML.

I get the document via `xhr.responseXML`, the result looks like this:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Style id="1">
      <IconStyle>
        <color>7f66CC33</color>
        <Icon>
          <href />
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
       ...
    </Style>
    <Folder>
      ....
    </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Then I want to perform queries on it to select nodes.

```
    xmlDom.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
    xmlDom.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces","xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'");
    nodeList = xmlDom.selectNodes("/kml/Document/Folder");
```

But this isn't working for me.  I expect to get at least one node, but I get zero.

**Q1: Can anyone explain why this is not working?**

As I was looking into this, I discovered to my surprise that xpath is not supported in XML Documents in the browser, in a cross-browser fashion.  Apparently the `selectNodes()` function is an IE-only thing?

**Q2: Can anyone confirm this?**

If this is true, then what should I be doing for cross-browser node selection from an XML document, from within the browser.

**Q3: How do I do cross-browser XPath queries, on an XML document?**

---

ps: I specifically don't care about doing "xpath on html".  It's an XML document I'm querying.

Comment: ps: here's a cross-browser javascript class to do XPath. http://jmvidal.cse.sc.edu/talks/javascriptxml/xpathexample.html  This did not work for me, on FF6, and also I did not like the class name ad shape.  So I changed it a little to fit my needs, see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183369/cross-browser-xpath-implementation-in-javascript/7476028#7476028

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You have**:

```
xmlDom.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath"); 
xmlDom.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces","xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'"); 
nodeList = xmlDom.selectNodes("/kml/Document/Folder");
```

**Must be**:

```
xmlDom.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath"); 
xmlDom.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces","xmlns:x='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'"); 
nodeList = xmlDom.selectNodes("/x:kml/x:Document/x:Folder");
```

**Explanation**:

**Any unprefixed name in an XPath expression in considered to beling to "no namespace"**.

Therefore, the expression:

```
/kml/Document/Folder
```

attempts to select elements named `Folder` that are in "no namespace" but in the provided documents all elementa are in the default (non-null) `http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2` namespace and there is no element in "no namespace". This is why the XPath expression above can't select any element.

**The solution is** to register a namespace binding of a *non-empty* prefix to the default namespace and most importantly, use this prefix to prefix any name in the XPath expression.