# jQuery syntax for selecting XML nodes

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm-2011

We are currently in the preparating for upgrading CRM 2011 with UR 12, and there are a few pieces of javascript that might break after the upgrade.

The XML related functions are some of the ones highlighted as potential code. 
So I would like to replace these functions with JQuery equivalent, but do not have much idea about jQuery

Assuming that 'result' is a XML response from xmlhttprequest, how do we convert the following code to use jquery

```
result.selectNodes("//EntityMetadata/DisplayName/LocLabels/LocLabel/Label");
```

will something like

```
$(result).find(("//EntityMetadata/DisplayName/LocLabels/LocLabel/Label");
```

Comment: Where is this XML coming from? OData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Despite this takes not your question regarding jQuery into account, it shows a way described in the CRM SDK.*

Take a look at the [JavaScript Best Practices article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7840a25-f25e-409b-8b6a-0ef04c7ed9c4#BKMK_JavaScriptBestPractices). This article links to [a sample where  a compatible implementation of selectNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594428) is shown

```
function _selectNodes(node, XPathExpression) {
  if (typeof (node.selectNodes) != "undefined") {
   return node.selectNodes(XPathExpression);
  }
  else {
   var output = [];
   var XPathResults = node.evaluate(XPathExpression, node, _NSResolver, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
   var result = XPathResults.iterateNext();
   while (result) {
    output.push(result);
    result = XPathResults.iterateNext();
   }
   return output;
  }
 };
```

Comment: thank you for the reference above. Looks like a good solution, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that jQuery [once had rudimentary XPath support](http://docs.jquery.com/API/1.1.2/DOM/Traversing/Selectors#XPath_Selectors). However, this does not seem to be the case anymore. You may find [*Cross-browser XPath implementation in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183369/cross-browser-xpath-implementation-in-javascript) interesting.

Also, there's no *requirement* that the result of `XMLHttpRequest` be XML. It could be text, JSON, binary data, etc.