# Google Apps Script: Directly accessing a XML element

Tags: javascript, xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I get the element value of `<PeriodLength>` in the XML document below?

```
<AnnualPeriods>
     <FiscalPeriod Type="Annual" EndDate="2009-06-30" FiscalYear="2009">
        <Statement Type="**INC**">
             <FPHeader>
                 <PeriodLength>**12**</PeriodLength>
                 <periodType Code="M">Months</periodType>
```

This is my current code snippet:

```
for (var k = 0; k < statements.length; k++) {     
   var values = elements[i].getChildren('Statement')[k]
       .getChildren('lineItem');
   var statementType = elements[i].getChildren('Statement')[k]
       .getAttribute('Type'); // INC, BAL, CAS
   var header = elements[i].getChildren('Statement')[k]
       .getChild('FPHeader');
   var periodLength = header.getChild('PeriodLength');
   var periodType = header.getChild('periodType');
}
```

Instead of looping through the statements, I would like to "directly" access them by specifying the element as a "path", e.g. `INC/PeriodLength`.

How would you recommend doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no XPath type capability in the Apps Script XML service. There some other 3rd party XML JavaScript parsers you can look into for this capability.

Some ideas here -

[Cross-browser XPath implementation in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183369/cross-browser-xpath-implementation-in-javascript)

Comment: How can I access these in Google Apps Script?

Comment: You can easily copy paste the code into a new gs file. See some thoughts on this here - http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/11/using-open-source-libraries-in-apps.html